# Delete Image From Storage

Tags: java, android, file

I want to delete an image file from storage but it returns false.

I created in my app, I can delete it but when I reinstall my app I can show it but I can't delete it

Here's my code:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    File file = new File(cartPostalDbs.get(position).getFilePath());
    boolean deleted = file.delete();
    if (deleted) {
        cartPostalDbs.remove(mPos);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Can Not Delete File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here's my file path

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/yadim/1/1558.jpg
```

and I check PERMISSION and use this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: i created in my app, i can delete it but when i reInstall my app i can show it but i can`t delete it

Comment: You use an Android 11 device?

Comment: Please change the title of your post to `Delete image from storage after reinstall`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you need, it works in multiple cases:

•If you want to delete a directory ( folder )
•If the file/directory that you want to delete doesn't exist

here is the code:

```
public void deleteFile(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);

    if (!file.exists()) return;

    if (file.isFile()) {
        file.delete();
        return;
    }

    File[] fileArr = file.listFiles();

    if (fileArr != null) {
        for (File subFile : fileArr) {
            if (subFile.isDirectory()) {
                deleteFile(subFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            if (subFile.isFile()) {
                subFile.delete();
            }
        }
    }

    file.delete();
}
```

usage:

```
deleteFile(cartPostalDbs.get(position).getFilePath());
```

your final code should look like this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
try {
deleteFile(cartPostalDbs.get(position).getFilePath());
boolean deleted = true;
} catch ( Exception e ) { boolean deleted = false; }
if (deleted) {
    cartPostalDbs.remove(mPos);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Can Not Delete File", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
I tried to edit the code to request the permission if it isn't granted :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
try {
    deleteFile(cartPostalDbs.get(position).getFilePath());
    boolean deleted = true;
} catch ( Exception e ) { boolean deleted = false; }
if (deleted) {
        cartPostalDbs.remove(mPos);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {

    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1000);

}
}
```

Add the onActivityResult void to delete the file when the permission is granted :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
    switch (requestCode) {
            case 1000:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == 
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
                        deleteFile(cartPostalDbs.get(position).getFilePath());
                        boolean deleted = true;
                } catch ( Exception e ) { boolean deleted = false; }
                if (deleted) {
                            cartPostalDbs.remove(mPos);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Can Not Delete File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Can Not Delete File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
            break;
            default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to add the permission to the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: your way is good and i try it before, but still i have no idea why it`s not working, any way thank you.

Comment: First sorry for being late .. please read **Edit 1**.